# How to get all rows from Sqlite 3 with the Sqlite-net package to a List of objects?

Tags: sql, xamarin, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm using this pacakage: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net
I can insert the List of objects just fine into the database.
However, I can't seem to be able to "GET * FROM TABLE" to a List.
I'm aware of the built-in function in this package. Before trying this I was using:

`return (List<MyClass>)(from i in connection.Table<MyClass>() select i).ToList();`

This worked just fine. However, I now need to create a Manual SQL query.

Here is roughtly what I thought it would look like:

```
List<MyClass> Temp = new List<MyClass>();
var Result = connection.Execute("SELECT * FROM Car MyTable");
while (Result.HasRows())
{
    Temp.Add(Result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `CreateCommand` with a `ExecuteDeferredQuery` to get a lazy cursor:

```
var sqlQueryEnumerable = sqlConn.CreateCommand("select * from Customer").ExecuteDeferredQuery<SomeTableClass>();
foreach (var row in sqlQueryEnumerable)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(row.SomeColumn);
}
```

If you need a `List`as your example code shows versus an `IEnumerable`, use `ExecuteQuery`:

```
var listOfCustomers = sqlConn.CreateCommand("select * from Customer").ExecuteQuery<Customer>();
foreach (var listItem in listOfCustomers)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(listItem.CustomerID);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the generic in `ExecuteQuery<MyClass>();` ? Does it justs act as a cast? Because The type if fine, but I have multiple tables that match that have the same structure of the MyClass class

Comment: @JimLahey The generic defines the return type of the table data, thus each of your SQL rows is transformed to that class definition.

Comment: Ok so it doesnt act like `return (List<MyClass>)(from i in connection.Table<MyClass>() select i).ToList();` Which only gets data from a table called `MyClass`?

Comment: @JimLahey Correct, but the data returned from your SQL statement needs to conform to that class type, otherwise you need to supply the table mapping options (second parameter to that method)